# MVC 4 - Error message from controller is not being displayed in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC website that when a field loses focus it will read a backend database and determine if the value is valid. If the value is valid it will fill in two other fields on the page. The problem I am having is when the value is invalid and I want to display an error message just like a validation message under the text box.

The view....

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)    
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HSDRepCode)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HSDRepCode, new { placeholder = "Enter your HSD Rep code...", @class = "contact-name" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HSDRepCode)
</div>
```

The calling script...

```
$("#HSDRepCode").blur(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/CRM/ValidateHSDRep",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function (model) {
            $("#HSDRepCode").val(model.HSDRepCode);
            $("#HSFirstName").val(model.HSFirstName);
            $("#HSLastName").val(model.HSLastName);
        });
    });
```

The model....

```
public class LeadInfo
{
    [Display(Name = "Products of Interest")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a product of interest")]
    public string Product { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "HSD Rep code")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your HSD Rep code")]
    [StringLength(6)]
    public string HSDRepCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "HSD Rep first name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your first name")]
    public string HSFirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "HSD Rep last name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your last name")]
    public string HSLastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Doctor's first name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the doctor's first name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Doctor's last name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the doctor's last nname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Doctor's phone number")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the doctor's phone number")]
    [Phone]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Doctor's e-mail")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the doctor's e-mail")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

and the controller....

```
public ActionResult ValidateHSDRep(LeadInfo leadInfo)
{
    HSDRep hsdRep = new HSDRep();

    hsdRep = CRMModels.ValidateHSDRepCode(leadInfo.HSDRepCode);

    if (hsdRep.FirstName != null)
    {
        leadInfo.HSFirstName = hsdRep.FirstName;
        leadInfo.HSLastName = hsdRep.LastName;

        return Json(leadInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("HSDRepCode", "Invalid HS Representative Code");

        return Json(leadInfo);
    }
}
```

The controller routine is called when the textbox loses focus.

How do I display the message "Invalid Representative Code" under the text box "HSDRepCode"?

Thanks,
Gary

**UPDATED:** I have added the Ajax code that calls the controller function.
**UPDATE 2:** I changed the return to return Json.

Comment: Why do you have both `return Json()` and `return View()` - how are you calling this?

Comment: Re: your edit - you are returning `json`, not the view. You do not hit the else block, so nothing gets added to `ModelState` and if it did, the ajax call would fail anyway since that returns html (not json)

Comment: After changing it to return Json it still does not display the error message.

Comment: You need to pass the message as part of the json response and then access it in the ajax success callback, but you should really be using a `[Remote]` attribute for this

Comment: Is there a way to return data back to the view using [Remote]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ValidateHSDRep()` method is returning json which has no concept of model state. In addition, you are unnecessarily degrading performance by sending the whole model to the view, then sending it all back again when you only need to send one property and return two. Change you script to send only the `HSDRepCode` value, and return only what you need

```
var url = '@Url.Action("ValidateHSDRep", "CRM");
$("#HSDRepCode").blur(function () {
  $.getJSON(url, { HSDRepCode: $(this).val() }, function(response) {
    if (response.ErrorMessage) {
      // do something with the error message
    } else {
      $("#HSFirstName").val(response.HSFirstName);
      $("#HSLastName").val(response.HSLastName);
      // remove any associated error message that may have been added in previous calls
    }
  });
});
```

and change the controller method to

```
public ActionResult ValidateHSDRep(string hSDRepCode)
{
  HSDRep hsdRep = CRMModels.ValidateHSDRepCode(hSDRepCode);
  if (hsdRep.FirstName == null)
  {
    return Json(new { ErrorMessage = "Invalid HS Representative Code" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  else
  {
    return Json(new { HSFirstName = hsdRep.FirstName, HSLastName = hsdRep.LastName; }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

However, since you are including `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HSDRepCode)` in the view, you can handle the 'invalid code' using a `RemoteAttribute` on you model property

```
[Display(Name = "HSD Rep code")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your HSD Rep code")]
[StringLength(6)]
[Remote("IsHSDRepCodeValid", "CRM", ErrorMessage = "Invalid HS Representative Code")]
public string HSDRepCode { get; set; }
```

then add a controller method

```
public JsonResult IsHSDRepCodeValid(string HSDRepCode)
{
  // code to test if valid
  if(isValid)
  {
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
  }
  else
  {
    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) // displays default message defined in ErrorMessage property
    // or
    return Json("a custom message", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
  }
}
```

Refer also [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28VS.98%29.aspx) for more detail on using remote validation

Comment: You show two sets of code. In the first you have a comment of "do something with the error message". What do I do with the error message? Is there a way to display it as the validation message. For the second sample is there a way to return the first and last name of the rep? Thanks

Comment: (1) For the first example, add an element for the message `<span class="field-validation-error" ><span id="invalidcode" ></span></span>`, then you can do something like `$('#invalidcode').text(reponse.ErrorMessage);` if there is an error. (2) No, the `RemoteAttribute` works by returning only one value - `true` or `false` (or a `string` - i.e. an error message)

Comment: I'm using option 1 because I need to pass back data. When I execute this I receive  "JavaScript runtime error: 'reponse' is undefined"

Comment: Sorry, just a typo - should be `response`. Also left `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` off the `return Json` block. See updated answer

Answer (score -1):

First parameter of `.AddModelError` method is `key`, which in your case is `HSDRepCode`, not `hsdrepcode`.

So:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("HSDRepCode", "Invalid Representative Code");
```

It's working ? Thanks

Comment: I modified the line to "ModelState.AddModelError("HSDRepCode", "Invalid HS Representative Code");" and it still does not display.

Comment: It not case sensitive - you could use `hSDrEpCODe` and it would work, so this is not the issue